# What is the best known upper bound for $( \gamma_{n+1}-\gamma_{n})\max_{\{T\in(\gamma_{n},\gamma_{n+1})\}}(\vert\zeta(1/2+iT)\vert) $?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

For  $ n $ a positive integer, denote by  $ L(n) : =\gamma_{n+1}-\gamma_{n} $ with  $ \gamma_{n} $ the imaginary part of the  $ n $-th critical zero of the Riemann zeta function and by  $ M(n) : =\max_{T\in(\gamma_{n},\gamma_{n+1})}(\vert\zeta(1/2+iT)\vert) $.

What is the best currently known upper bound for  $ L(n)M(n) $ in terms of  $ T_{n}=(\gamma_{n}+\gamma_{n+1})/2 $? I'm interested in both unconditional results and stronger ones assuming RH and possibly Montgomery's pair correlation conjecture.